# Programmatically determining the label title for a button

Tags: javascript

I am trying to set the text for my button to one of three possibilities.

The default will be 'Submit'

However, it could be be 'Pending...' Or 'Please Try Later' depending on some conditions.

How can I handle these 3 conditions in a better way?

Right now I only have:

`bText = pending ? 'Pending...' : 'Please try later';`

Comment: use a [switch](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp)

Comment: ^that. you can chain switch statements.

Answer (score 0):

In order to handle 3 conditions, you need 2 booleans.

So you'll have to add an extra boolean, maybe called **submit** for example

```
bText = pending ? 'Pending...' : submit ? 'Submit' : 'Please try later';
```